# Converting an XML GuzzleHttp\Client (laravel) response to JSON retreive only the header

Tags: xml, laravel, api, guzzle

I'm trying to convert an XML response received via GuzzleHttp into JSON, if I print the response in the console I see it as "XML" text complete with all the data.

At the moment I try to convert the XML into JSON but the only thing that comes back to me is {"@attributes":{"version":"1.0"}} as well as the header line containing the XML version.

**Part of the answer obtained via Postman:**

[POST response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE7yE.png)

**PHP code (Laravel) to request and transform the data:**

```
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post('https://api.opentransportdata.swiss/ojp2020', 
[ 'headers' => $headers, 'body' => $body, 'verify' => false]);

$xml = $response->getBody()->getContents();

$data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), true);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330626/laravel-guzzlehttp-xml-response-to-json

Comment: Is what I've posted...